# VBA:How to modify the color of the text from the clipboard before pasting

Tags: vba, colors, clipboard

I have lots of copy-paste to do in Microsoft Word and after pasting, I need to put the pasted text with a different color than black.

> Sub PasteUnformattedText()
>
> Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
>
> Selection.Font.Color = 12611584
>
> Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
>
> End Sub

What do I need to do to change the color of the pasted text? I've tried with "Selection.Font.Color = 12611584 ", but the color still remains the default one: the black.

Comment: Have you tried setting the font color after you paste?

Comment: No, but you gave my idea which helped a lot. Just before pasting the text, I just add a empty space in to the document. THANX!

Comment: Great! Please considering answering your question with your functioning code for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Just add

> Dim MyText As String
>
> ```
> MyText = " "
>
> Selection.TypeText (MyText)
> ```

before

> Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText